# large html table to pdf using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, html-table, fpdf

I am converting a html table to pdf using php and fpdf,the problem is that for a table with large number of columns the data is going outside the pdf page.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: What would you like it to do? Here are some ideas if you need it to stay within the bounds on the page and not wraparound: reduce the font, reduce padding/margin, and make the page landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), it allow you to control every mm of page. It's well documented.

See the [example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) n.11 for table or use it to write html inside pdf.